# show one object of a class in listview C#

Tags: c#, android, class, listview, xamarin.android

I am making an app with xamarin in c#.
this is my code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Skylander> adapter;    
ListView List = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.LstSkylanders);
List.Adapter = adapter;
```

my class:

```
class Skylander
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Power { get; set; }
            public int Protection { get; set; }
            public int Speed { get; set; }
            public int Luck { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string StringName= "Name: " + Name;
                return StringName;
            }
        };
```

My function to make a string to number:

```
public int ToNumber(string number)
        {
            int temp;
            try
            {
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(number);
            } catch { temp = 0; };
            return temp;
        }
```

And this is how I add a Skylander to the list:

```
Skylander New = new Skylander { Name = Name.Text, Power = ToNumber(Power.Text), Protection = ToNumber(Protection.Text),Speed = ToNumber(Speed.Text), Luck = ToNumber(Luck.Text)};

                adapter.Add(New.ToString());
```

This is my output:[image: Output]

I am trying to only show the name in my listview.
I hope you can help me.

Danny

Comment: Maybe it's me, but is ArrayAdapter being initialized? It doesn't look like it knows what kind of layout to use. `ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter (this,
Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, data);
ListAdapter = adapter;`

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/use_an_arrayadapter/

Comment: sorry, i forgot to include this code: adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Skylander>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);

Comment: What is it currently showing? And, is there a value in `Name`?

Comment: Maybe update the code in the question with the adapter init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from Java.Lang.Object, as Xamarin compiler uses java version of toString, leave everything else untouched

```
 class Skylander: Java.Lang.Object{

    .....

     public override string ToString()
                {
                    string StringName= "Name: " + Name;
                    return StringName;
                }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works. But I am trying to display the name and when you Longcross it, it displays all the information.